# DB2 record have timestamps from multiple timezones

Tags: db2

Hi I have a db2 DB on mainframe that has data being written to by a web app and phone voice telephony ivr app.   They were all located in the Central us time zone.  The web app is being rewritten and moved to Eastern US time. The insert records all use sysdate for records timestamps like when the record was created or last updated.    Since the db queries are "select ...... order by create_time" or "select .... order by update_time"  The different time zones cause order problems.

I want a way to display all the records in one TZ (probably eastern).

```
select some_time_util(*,easternTZ) from table where condition=easternTz order by some_time_util( create_date, easten_tz)
union
select some_time_util(*,centralTZ) from table where condition=centralTz order by some_time_util( create_date, centeral_tz)
```

how is db2 supporting the concept of timestamsp and timezones?

Comment: Not all versions of DB2 handle different timezones.  Which version and platform, please?  It's also usually better to store 'absolute' UTC stamps for logged actions, and just translate on output (if necessary).  Note that invoking a function on a column used in an `ORDER BY` is likely to ignore any indices, although with timestamps it may be smart enough to amortize this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is supported by DB2 - check out Time zone specific expressions

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_tzspecificexpression.dita

Comment: %headdesk% - IBM fails for conflating time zone and offset.  These are **NOT** the same thing.  You can go from zone to offset (...with some caveats), but not the other way (because there are multiple zones with the same offset).  There's a bigger problem with trying to use timestamps like this: think about what happens when daylight savings time shows up...